# get a JS value in php

Tags: php, javascript

I have a js function to return a title of a song and another one to return the artist of the same song. then I have another function which makes a string combining the name and the artist. finally I want to print that string in php. 
this is my js:

```
function getName(){

      return artist+ ", " + title;
  }
```

and  this is my php:

```
echo '<script>getName();</script>';
```

but this doesnt return anything. what am I missing??

Answer (score 5):

You must still output the return value:
`echo '<script>document.write(getName());</script>';` does not need jQuery, but is simple vanilla javascript.

Comment: is the function in a seperate javascript or included in the php?

Comment: @SaeedNajafi I don't know how you implemented it, but a quick [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/TeefY/) confirms this is working just fine.

Comment: where is your artist and title variable? How does this function get those?

Comment: this is what I have: echo '<script> document.write(getName()); </script>'; its the same right? :)

Comment: yes but your function needs access to the variables. Currently that function expects them to be globally. Try (for testing): `echo '<script>artist='metallica'; title='black'; document.write(getName());</script>';`

Comment: @GitaarLAB I am using last fm API, and I have two global variables song and artist and I have a function in my js that extract the title and artist from the url and then equals to those variables

Comment: And did the test-code in my previous comment output `'metallica, black'`? What does your browsers error-log say? We probably need more code.

Answer (score 2):

You're not putting it on screen.

`alert(getName());` would work. Same goes for `$('.element').text(getName());` or something similar.

Comment: document.write(getName()); is better?

Comment: Whatever, he'll be fine as long as he does something with the output rather than just calling the function.

Answer (score 1):

There's not a plausible way of doing this on a standard configuration. Javascript is evaluated after the PHP is. The PHP executes, then the server sends the results to the clients browser. The browser then renders that result, and THEN executes javascript. May I ask why you are doing this? It seems overly complicated. Why not just: `document.write(getName());`?

Comment: Completely offtopic: but I've been wondering the last couple of day's why nobody made a php class that can interpret javascript (maybe no dom, ok, but ability to do basic javascript). Everything's possible right? I can't believe no-one has had a crack at that yet.

Comment: Sweet, Javascript V8 in PHP: http://php.net/manual/en/book.v8js.php, that in combination with that DOM class (could you post a link)... opens up very cool possibility's!